# how to select, selected option based on first select option after reload page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

**I have two select option in register.blade.php:**

If any one click on option **B.E./B.TECH.** OR **DIPLOMA** of Name of Course. Then based on selected **Name of Course** select option, result will be show in **Name of Branch**. All are working nice.

But Here text field **Name** is required and validation is set in controller. Now if I didn't fill name and select DIPLOMA from option first then result shows in second option field. And I select any option from results and submit the form. Then form will be redirect on register.blade.php, because of **Name** required. And selected option hide.

I want after submit the form, if redirect on same page then **Name of Branch** field should be show with selected option, If it has been selected.

**register.blade.php**

```
<form action="route('register')" method="post">
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<label for="name">Name* </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm required" id="alumni_name" name="alumni_name" placeholder="" value="{{ old('alumni_name') }}">
<span style="color: red;">{{ $errors->first('alumni_name',':message') }}</span>
</div>

<div class = "form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
<label for="years">Name of Course*</label> 
<select class="form-control input-sm required" id="courses_name" name="alumni_course"> 
<option value="">-- Select Any one --</option> 
@foreach($coursename as $coursenames) 
<option value="{{ $coursenames->id.','.$coursenames->coursename }}" {{ old('alumni_course') == $coursenames->id.','.$coursenames->coursename ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{ $coursenames->coursename }}</option> 
@endforeach 
</select>
<span style="color: red;">{{ $errors->first('alumni_course',':message') }}</span> 
</div>

<div class = "form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="dvPassport" style="display:none"> 
<label for="years">Name of Branch*</label> 
<select class="form-control input-sm required" id="branch_name" name="alumni_branch">
@include('auth.branchfind') 
</select> 
</div>
<input type="submit" value="SAVE">
</form>
```

**AJAX on same page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#courses_name").change(function(){
         var courses_name1 = $("#courses_name").val();
         var courses_name2 = courses_name1.split(",");
         var id = courses_name2[0];
         var courses_name2 = courses_name2[1];
         if(courses_name2 == 'B.E./B.TECH.' || courses_name2 == 'DIPLOMA')
         {
         $("#dvPassport").show();
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "{{url("findbranch")}}",
            data: {'id': id},
         }).done(function(data){
            $("#branch_name").html(data);
              //console.log(data);
         });
         }
         else {
            $("#dvPassport").hide();
        }
      });
   });
</script>
```

**branchfind.blade.php is:**

```
<option value=''>Select Any One</option>
@if(isset($branchname)) 
@foreach($branchname as $branchnames) 
<option value="{{ $branchnames->id }}" {{ old('alumni_branch') == $branchnames->id ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{ $branchnames->branchname }}</option> 
@endforeach 
@endif
```

**function in controller for AJAX request is:**

```
public function findbranch(Request $request)
{
     $branchname = branchname::where('course_id', $request->id)->get();
    return view('auth.branchfind')->with(compact('branchname'))->render();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$validator = Validator::make($rules,$request->all());
  if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
```